# Able to run Python3 Script through IDE, Command Line, but not by double clicking or Task Scheduler

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv, scheduled-tasks

So I have written a script that scrapes betting data from an odds aggregating site and outputs everything into a CSV. My script works perfectly, however, I can only run it from within Spyder. Whenever I double click the PY file a terminal opens up and closes quickly. After messing around with it for a while I also discovered that I can run it through the command line.

I have the program/script line pointing to my python3:
C:\Users\path\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe

And my argument line points to the script
\networkname\path\moneylineScraper.py

Best case scenario I would like to be able to run this script through task scheduler, but I also cannot even run it when I double click the Py file. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This probably has to do with absolute and relative paths. Jou can try to make a shortcut linking `python myscript.py` and working directory `my_work_dir` and let the task scheduler invoke that.

Comment: I tried messing around with my paths and explicitly stating the path with my Anaconda version of Python and still got nowhere. However I am inexperienced and may be misinterpreting what you are saying. I believe my issue may be related to me having multiple versions of Python on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is, to create a bat file and then execute it.

A new bat file:

-- change directory to that of python script file.
-- using full path execute python with script file as argument.
-- End the batch file.

Make that bat file executable with sufficient previlages and execute that.